# How to distinguish individuals from groups in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have panel data that that I want to visualize using `ggplot2` such that each individual gets its own line and its color reflects the group that it is apart of. For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
frame <- data.frame(id = 1:6, month1 = sample(0:1, 6, replace = TRUE), month2 = sample(0:1, 6, replace = TRUE), month3 = sample(0:1, 6, replace = TRUE), group1 = rep(0:1, 3), group2 = rep(1:0, 3))
frame2 <- reshape(data = frame, direction = "long", idvar = "id", timevar = "time", varying = list(2:4))
ggplot(frame2, aes(x = time, y = month1, group = id, colour = id)) + geom_smooth()
```

In this plot, I would like each member of group1 to be red and each member of gruop2 to be blue and have each individual get its own line. Any idea on how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: If I was to guess, I think its because your group variables are numeric. If you cast them as factors then the two groups should be different colours rather than on a scale. If that doesn't answer your question could you show your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. You might consider jittering the lines as well if in your real application the Y axis variable is discrete.

```
ggplot(frame2, aes(x = time, y = month1, group = as.factor(id), 
       colour = as.factor(group2))) + geom_smooth()
```

[image]